# Refine search get aspx pages only based on tags

Tags: search-results, filter, search-scope, tags, result-source

I have to search all the aspx pages in my site-collection based on tags. For example - Tag "finance" has been added to finReport.aspx and denialsReport.aspx. So when user search finanace, it should return only these two aspx pages.

I am following this [link](http://www.sharepoint24x7.com/2014/10/01/article-customizing-sharepoint-2013-results-using-result-sources/), but it doesnot have "Tag" search in it. Please provide any links or basic ideas on this. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a **Result source**, a **Query rule** and a **Managed Property** mapped to Tags column.

- Result Source would define that Search should return values form
  pages directory. Use **path** identifier here.
- Query rule will define that your keyword matches managed property.

Follow [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/02/01/how-query-rules-and-result-sources-can-be-used-to-customize-search-results.aspx) link

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your query

Answer (score 0):

A managed property against your tagging column should be enough to fulfill your requirement.

Follow the below steps to get your content returned by searching against the tagging fields.

Create a page by tagging -> Crawl your content source (site) -> Crawled property will be created (for tagging column) -> Create a search managed through UI or PowerShell.

Search using the search query TaggingColumn1:Finance, will return all the pages where the search managed property TaggingColumn1 contains Finance.

Ref: [Overview of crawled and managed properties in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/jj219630.aspx)

Comment: I have two question here:
1. Why cant I use "Items matching a tag"  result source? I tried setting it as default and added tags in "Tags and Notes" for most of the aspx pages. Full crawled. Tried searching for tags. But it didnot work.
2. Created a column in Doc Lib - "EdwTags" -> full crawl -> crawl property created "EdwTagsOWSTEXT" -> mapped to "EdwTags" -> Searched like EdwTags:Finance. But it didnot work either